# Use my old mac book as a monitor for my Windows 7

Tags: windows, mac, multiple-monitors

It's old 2007 macbook running lion i believe, ( I haven't used it in a while cannot remember which i updated it to, the log in has round circles if anyone can make sense of that.)

I've tried maxivista, although i could not get it to work as on the mac it didn't have many option for me to play with.

Comment: Do you want to use the old macbook as sole monitor (RDP/VNC like), as additonal second monitor or as hardware monitor?

Comment: Second monitor.

Comment: This might work for you:  http://synergy-foss.org/

Comment: Only problem with this is that it just share my mouse :(